# prove that a subset of complex numbers is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider the set $\{a + b2^{\frac{1}{3}}:a,b\in{\bf{Q}}\}$. I am trying to prove that this set is not a subfield of the complex number field $\bf{C}$. I tried to prove that the set is not closed under multiplication. If the product of two elements in this set was contained in the set, then it must be that $2^{\frac{2}{3}}=a+b2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ for $(a,b)\in{\bf{Q}}\times{\bf{Q}}$. It seems clear that in such an expression $a\neq{0}$ (else it is easy to get a contradiction). But I cannot see how to proceed beyond this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: write $\;2^{\frac{2}{3}}=a+b2^{\frac{1}{3}}\;$ as $u^2 = a+bu$ with $u=\sqrt[3]{2} \iff u^3 = 2$, then multiplying by $u$:

$$
2 = u^3 = au+bu^2 = au + b\left(a+bu\right)=ab+(a+b^2)u
$$

Comment: I think this solves it! Solve for u and get (2- ab)/(a+b) = u forcing one to conclude that u must be rational which is a contradiction.

Comment: @student Right, after you exclude the $a+b=0$ case which leads to another contradiction $2 = -a^2\,$.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say!!

Comment: I found a very slight error- it is easily fixed. The argument by dxiv basically works. In the above displayed identity, $2 = au +b(a+bu) = ab + (a + b^2)u$. If $(a+b^2) = 0$, so that $a = -b^2$, then $2 = ab = -b^3$ which is impossible for rational $b$ (since $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is an irrational number. Thus, $(a + b^2)$ must be non-zero, and the implied identity $(2 - ab)/(a + b^2) = u$ implies that $u$ must be a rational number which is impossible.

Comment: @student Fixed, thanks for catching that. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sqrt[3]{2}$; since $u^3=2$ and the polynomial $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ by Eisenstein’s criterion, it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence $x^3-2$ is the minimal polynomial of $u$.

By general theory of algebraic field extensions, the minimal subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $u$ has dimension $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since your vector subspace contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and $u$, but has dimension at most $2$ (actually $2$), it cannot be a subfield.